# Creating a downloadable PDF from a wordpress webpage

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, pdf

I'm currently working on a configurator page on a clients wordpress website.

https://gof.co.uk/test-configurator/

They want to ability to select options on the product and then download a pdf with the image and selections listed. So it will look something like this  - [PDF concept image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz0Lo.jpg)

Is there any way to do this? I'm at a bit of a loss.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: look at wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to add a button prompting the browsers print window, from there you can save as PDF based on your print media CSS. As far as I know there's no way to directly trigger the save as PDF.

The other solution is to use a library such as jsPDF (javascript) or MPDF (PHP). But then you need to "remake" the page using their syntaxes. You can read more about both libraries here:
jsPDF https://parall.ax/products/jspdf
MPDF https://mpdf.github.io/

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll give them a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to format for printing give instructions to save to PDF.

You can link a stylesheet like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
   src="print.css"
   type="text/css"
   media="print" />
```

An alternative to the previous approach is media queries. Anything you add inside this block will apply to printed documents.

```
@media print {

}
```

Margins can be set like this.

```
@page {
  margin-top: 2cm;
  margin-bottom: 2cm;
  margin-left: 2cm;
  margin-right: 2cm;
}
```